# How in Unity get JSON data that has many variables in it?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I made this code that works when API text has one variable and it's value, but when text is like this my script doesn't work, how to fix it? I tryed to get only one variable but it didn't work and i got null.

API text that my code work with: https://catfact.ninja/fact

API text that my code does not work with: https://randomuser.me/api

I edited code to get data from many variables JSON, but again got null:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Service : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _text;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetRequest("https://randomuser.me/api"));
}

private IEnumerator GetRequest(String url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        switch (webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
            _text.text = "Error: " + webRequest.error;
            break;

            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
            _text.text = "HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error;
            break;

            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
            if (CheckAPI(webRequest))
            {
                Name name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Name>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);

                if (name.title == null || name.first == null || name.last == null)
                {
                    _text.text = "Error: no information with such variables";
                }
                else
                {
                    _text.text = name.title + " " + name.first + " " + name.last;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _text.text = "Error: there are no API data";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckAPI(UnityWebRequest data)
{
    string contentType = data.GetResponseHeader("Content-Type");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) && contentType.Contains("application/json"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Name
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public void NewRequest()
{
    Start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need just a name you can parse a json string and deserilaize a name property

```
 Name name = JObject.Parse(webRequest.downloadHandler.text)["results"][0]["name"]
                    .ToObject<Name>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are working with a class "Fact" with (I suppose) this structure (or similar):

```
public class Fact
{
    public string fact { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
}
```

and you are deserializating the json to the object with:

```
 Fact fact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fact>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
```

but in the second example the response is different, so you need these classes:

```
public class myNewClass
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public Info info { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinates
{
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Dob
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string seed { get; set; }
    public int results { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Street street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int postcode { get; set; }
    public Coordinates coordinates { get; set; }
    public Timezone timezone { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string sha1 { get; set; }
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}

public class Registered
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public Dob dob { get; set; }
    public Registered registered { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Picture picture { get; set; }
    public string nat { get; set; }
}



public class Street
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Timezone
{
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

and deserializate with:

```
myNewClass myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myNewClass>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
```

of course, change the name of your main class to whatever you want.

You can work with this or any other case using the following tool:

https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I edited code with your advice, but again got zero. Edited code I added in question.

Comment: because you have to process all the response, or just the name as @Serge told you